# Difference between open URL methods in AppDelegate of iOS app

Tags: ios, swift, appdelegate

I was using this method in my AppDelegate file to handle app opening with my URL scheme

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, open url: URL, 
                 sourceApplication: String?, annotation: Any) -> Bool {}
```

Later I added other method (iOS 9.0 is needed)

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, open url: URL,
                 options: [UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey : Any]) -> Bool {}
```

Now I see that second method handles all app launches.

1. What is the difference between this methods?
2. Should I just fill them with the same logic, so that my first method will be only executed on iOS 8 devices.
3. Can i delete my first method if i am not interested in supporting iOS 8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First method have support from iOS 4.0 to iOS 9.0. Now it is Deprecated. 
And From 9.0 iOS provide new method for openURL that is your second method.

Purpose of both method is same. so if want to give support for iOS 8 also than keep both method else remove Deprecated method.

You can see this in UIKit framework -> UIApplication.h (check below image)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

> Yes why not... you can delete ios 8 supporting open url method and update to ios 9 open url method...

Comment: so you say that there are no cases when first method is needed on iOS 9 and later? it will never get called instead of second?

Comment: if you update ios 9 open url method then no need of ios 8 open url method.. and you can remove that ios 8 open url method....